# How can I remove an array from my redux store?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying hard to remove an array. But it is not work. After delete my array length and data remain same.

This is my frontend react web page

```
renderAdmin = (id) => {
        
        if(this.props.auth.user.userType==='normal') return(<td></td>);
        return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <td>
                <button onClick={() => this.props.changeStatus(id)}
                className="ui button" >Change Status</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button onClick={() => this.props.deleteUser(id)}
                className="ui button" >Delete User</button>
            </td>
        </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
```

Here i am taking id of my array.

Now this is my redux action creator

```
export const deleteUser = (id) =>  (dispatch,getState) => {
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

  axios.delete(`/api/users/remove/${id}`, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `${user.token}`
    }
  }).then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data);
  
    dispatch({
      type: 'DELETE_USER',
      payload: res.data
  })

  dispatch({
      type: 'CREATE_ERROR',
      payload: 'User Delete'
  })
    
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
  })
}
```

Here first i remove it from backend server. That works fine. Then i send res.data to my reducer payload. DELETE_USER not working well. but CREATE_ERROR works fine.

This is my reducer

```
export default function (state = [] , action) {
    //  console.log(action)
      switch(action.type) {
          case 'ALL_USER' : return action.payload;  
          case 'EDIT_USER' :    
            return state.map(user=>{
                if(user._id === action.payload._id){
                    return action.payload;
                }
                else {
                    return user;
                }
            });
          case 'DELETE_USER' :
            return state.filter(user=>
                user !== action.payload
            )
          default : return state;
      }
  }
```

After pressing delete button, data remove from server but redux store always remain same. Please help me.
Thank You.

Comment: Why are you dispatching `CREATE_ERROR` from within `deleteUser` **outside** of your `catch` block?

Comment: CREATE_ERROR this is not exactly for error. You can say, this is for sending a message. Thats it.

Comment: `user !== action.payload` won't work because `action.payload` will be a separate object instance because it comes from `JSON.parse` (even it does represent the same "real-life" entity). You should be comparing `._id` values instead. Try this: `return state.filter( u => u._id !== action.payload.whateverTheUserIdPropertyIs )`

Comment: @Dai now i understand. Thanks brother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be due to the objects not being truly equal try filtering on the id instead:

```
return state.filter(user=>
                user._id !== action.payload._id
            )
```

Or check for deep equality.

Comment: Thats work brother. You are a life saver. Thank you very much. BTW can you please told me, "why user and action.payload not match?? Or why my previos code not work?

Comment: @Rupam Take a read of something like this https://medium.com/@nathanworden/deep-equality-in-javascript-objects-c98ec918e888